# Cannot ping across router (see details)

Tags: networking, router, ipv4, cisco, subnet

I'm trying to go through an online course to study for my CCENT and CCNA certification exams, and I've come across a trouble spot.

In the module, he's going over basic network setup, including setting up interfaces, assigning ip addresses, the works.

At the end of the video for that portion, he's testing the connection by pinging a second machine from across the router, and having no issue in doing so, however I can't seem to make it work. Crude ASCII topology drawing below.

Currently, I can ping both ends of the router from either machine, and can ping both machines from the router no problem. What am I missing, or what have I not done in order to be able to ping one machine to the other? I want to make sure I have this working before I move on in the course.

```
        10.0.0.0/25      10.0.0.128/25

|CPU 1|-------G0/0--|R1|--G0/1----------|CPU 2|

R1: G0/0: 10.0.0.1/25
    G0/1: 10.0.0.129/25
    CPU 1:10.0.0.10/25
        default gateway: 10.0.0.1
    CPU 2:10.0.0.130/25
        default gateway: 10.0.0.129
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the PCs in question "physical" machines?  One common cause for PC to PC ping failure on "Physical" machines is the windows firewall.  It would need to be disabled on the remote machine you wish to ping in order to get a response.

Thank you
Please vote on this answer if it was helpful.